Agentforce popup window is blank
I am unable to view Agentforce pop up window on help.salesforce.com website. Are you able to view properly? If I click on the three dots and download the conversation, I can see the default text sent by Agentforce.


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to open a case with Salesforce.
